# OS X Messages.app, cmd+shift+w not working

Tags: messages, keybindings

On my new mac,

I have noticed in **Messages.app**, I can no longer purge message threads via cmd+shift+w like I could on my old computer.  Every time I have to manually hit the "x" and delete them.

Update:  I am trying to **"close the conversation"** not delete it.

Thoughts on how to fix this or add the binding?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Not sure why some one has down voted this???

Comment: ok, I found that panel but for some reason that key command is not working to close the conversation.  any thoughts @markhunte on what would cause that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you mean. If you right-click on the conversation in the left-side of the conversation window (the circle user icons) you can choose "Close Conversation" instead of deleting the conversation.

[image]

I couldn't get the shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to work until I went into preferences and and checked the box to "Save history when conversations are closed". Then I could close the conversation from the list.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean delete Conversation.

Select the Conversation and use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>Delete</kbd>  keys

--update--

Looking at the help>show shortcuts.

It is supposed to.

[image]

But I do not see the menu option in mine.